# Rascal MPL Treemap squarification

Tags: treemap, rascal

How should I get the Rascal treemap to squarify?

Currently it is not squaring correctly as seen in the image below.

[image: Treemap example]

In the source code of the [Treemap](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/vis/figure/tree/TreeMap.java) file I can see the comment `Based on Mark Bruls; Kees Huizing and Jarke J. vanWijk. "Squarified Treemaps"`. However I don't see the squarification taking place in the source code.

Do I need to look elsewhere or is it not implemented?

**Edit**

So I tried this.  The most simple example is:

```
render(
        box(
             treemap(boxes),
             size(500,500)
        )
    );
```

I minimized the visualization window so it actually is 500x500 (I also tried 250x500 and vice versa).

In all situations it renders favoring rows:

[image: Updated example]

Comment: looks like it takes the aspect ratio of the surrounding window. What happens if you embed the whole treemap in a square box of a certain size?

Comment: @jurgenv bedankt, I updated my question

Comment: Did you hear an answer to this question already Bas?

Comment: I spoke to Atze about this. There is a problem in the layout, as you can see there is no switching between rows and columns, only rows are being rendered. Later this week I will validate changes to rascal that should fix this (ordering from big to small and the row/column selection based on aspect ratio). If it is fixed I will answer the question and mark it.

Comment: Ok very cool. Thanks Bas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout is now working as expected as of 2014-01-02